# Setting IBOutlet to nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Quick question, are these the same?

```
self.sliderLabel = nil;
```

AND

```
[self setSliderLabel: nil];
```

gary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are exactly the same.

In fact, at compile time `self.sliderLabel = nil;` becomes `[self setSliderLabel: nil];`.

Comment: Don't you mean, 'becomes `[self setSliderLabel: nil];`'

Comment: Fixed that 1 min before you commented :)